# How to Check if an iFrame Has a Value In It

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have the following iframe within a parent window:

```
<iframe
   name="sg_iframe" 
   id="sg_iframe" 
   src="www.myurl.com"
   align="left"
   height="150px" 
   width="750"
   frameborder="0" 
   marginheight="0" 
   marginwidth="0"
   overflow="auto">
</iframe>
```

Now within www.myurl.com, let’s say I have a report that display 3 fields based on some criteria.

So based on this, how can I check from the parent form whether the iframe described above is empty of data, i.e. no report data listed or actually does have data using jquery/javascript?

Basically just need to know if the report within the iframe has 0 rows or 1 or more rows.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the hostnames of the two pages exactly the same, or are they different?

Comment: The same - I just provided a dummy url in this example. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an internal URL, you can use jQuery's [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to get the page's content.

If it's an external URL, [you can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837717/get-html-of-external-url-in-jquery/3837727#3837727).

Comment: Thanks @uncollected. FYI, it's an internal URL but just need a flag of "Y" or "N" to see if the iframe has content, not concerned about the actual content so not sure how to do this check with jQuery's load function?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('iframe').each(function() {
    if($(this).contents().find('#content').text() == '') {
        $(this).addClass('warning');
    }
});
```

Comment: should your 'iframe' here be my 'sg_iframe' and what is '#content' - is this a standard id to do with iframes?