# Extract html of other domain page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

What i want to do:

Extract html of other domain.

What i have tried:

```
$.get("http://website1.com", function(data) {
alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

(not working)

(for example) im the owner of tow websites:

```
website1.com
website2.com
```

now i want to get the html of `website1.com` and then show the html in `website2.com` by using jquery or any other way (website2.com Support Client-side languages Only ,website1.com Support Php).

HOW Can I Do It(im the owner of website1 and website2)?

Comment: implement CORS, or JSONP. if you went to the console you would see *"Access Denied due to Same-Origin Policy"*, and if you googled that, you would have gotten this same information.

Comment: im the owner of website1 and website2, so i can give access to specific domain?

Comment: I guess you should take a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837717/get-html-of-external-url-in-jquery

Comment: @mnio112233 Yes, using CORS. Note that IE7 doesn't support CORS and IE8/9 only partially supports it (will need to extend jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an iframe to display a page on your page.

Answer (score 0):

Add following header to your website1 php will allow $.get() in website2 to get website1 content.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://website2.com');
```

Comment: i well try it, thank you!.