# How to get meta tags from remote url (javascript or Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get meta tags (description + title) from remote url with javascript or Jquery.

Here is the code I use for a keyup event:

```
$.get($("#form_url_site").val(), function(data) {
    var descr = $(data).find('meta[name=description]').attr("content");
    $('#form_texte_site').html(descr);
    var titre_site = $(data).find('title').attr("content");
    $('#form_titre_site').html(titre_site);
});
```

But I have the error returned:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.re/. Origin http://blogolink.blogolink.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

How can I manage that?... Is it possible with javascript? If not perhap's get it with javascript via a php file which can grab remote urls?
Thanks

Comment: Same origin policy `-->` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Comment: Echoing @pXL: More info on Same Origin `-->` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837717/get-html-of-external-url-in-jquery

Answer (score -2):

You need to create a script on your own server that requests that page, and you call that script using your ajax request.

E.g get the remote page through PHP to your server and then get the meta tags and other details.

```
    <?php
    // create curl resource
    $ch = curl_init();

    // set url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com");

    //return the transfer as a string
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // $output contains the output string
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    // close curl resource to free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);     
    ?>
```