# CSRF attack with FORM GET and IFRAME

Tags: javascript, html, forms, csrf

I'm try to see if a website is vulnerable to CSRF with following code

```html
<html>
<body>
<div>
<iframe width="0" height="0" border="0" name="dummyframe" id="dummyframe"></iframe>
<form action="TARGET_SITE" method="GET" id="get_site" target="dummyframe"></form>
<script>
document.getElementById("get_site").submit();
var e = document.getElementById("dummyframe");
if(e != null) {
   alert(e.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML);
}
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The iframe tag is added here to avoid the page redirect when the form is submitted from the java script. When the form is being submitted, i do see a HTML response with some interesting information which i would want access.

But how do i access that HTML response, either from the iframe or form tag, the alert window in the example pops up but it doesn't print anything.

Thanks

Comment: It alerts a blank alert for me, but one with many lines. What is in your target_file file?

Comment: Target is a URL like https://stackoverflow.com/, basically a html response.

Comment: Your problem is that you're not putting the HTML response into the iframe. Is that what you want to fix? I'd recommend AJAX/jQuery in that case.

Comment: My Goal is to retrieve HTML response for the form being submitted (browser adds the target site's cookies), but without iframe as a target the page redirects to target site. Any approach to retrieve HTML response would answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is obtain the HTML of an external page and add that to an `<iframe>`, then you need to use a server-side language (NodeJS, PHP, Python), because of this reason (thanks @Hannes):

> All common Browsers do not allows Javasript Calls to access any Pages with another (sub)Domain because of the Same Origin Policy. The only way to work around that is to set up some kind of "proxy" on your own server (for example an php Script) that runs under the same Domain, gets the Information you want from a third source and prints them out.

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837717/get-html-of-external-url-in-jquery/3837799#3837799).

Comment: Don't copy the answer... propose to close this one as a duplicate instead

Comment: All I want to do is retrieve a webpage from different domain using FORM GET method (so that cookies are added by browser) and access the HTML response which contains a important string, that would make the attack successful. Its not necessary for the approach to use iframe.