# Implementing CSRF in webapp

Tags: java, spring, csrf

I am following [this](https://dzone.com/articles/preventing-csrf-java-web-apps) for prevent CSRF in my webapp.

I could implement the same, but I have a minor doubt regarding how it exactly secures my webapp. We are creating an encrypted `String` along with the `form` with `input type="hidden"`. So far so good. The user is not aware of the attribute that is passed along when submitting a form.

But, if the attacker is keen and finds the input element `(document.getElementById/Name)`, and uses JS to get the value out of the form and use it in the malicious request, *How is it exactly helping here?* My server would still keep allowing the request to go through since the malicious request also might be having the same encrypted `String` as hidden input.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSRF attack with FORM GET and IFRAME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52462888/csrf-attack-with-form-get-and-iframe)

Comment: Check out this answer, or the one it links to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52463001/3838167

Comment: Unless the attacker also has access to the session cookie/session id there is no issue. If the attacker also has access to the session cookie you have other issues at your hand.

Comment: If you are also using CORS , CSRF will be effective as the attacker even though he might be using the token in the js , the server won't accept a request from another domain.

Answer (score 0):

A CSRF token is a random, hard-to-guess string. On a page with a form you want to protect, the server would generate a random string, the CSRF token, add it to the form as a hidden field and also remember it somehow, either by storing it in the session or by setting a cookie containing the value.

When the user submits the form, the server simply has to compare the value of the posted field csrf-token (the name doesn’t matter) with the CSRF token remembered by the server. If both strings are equal, the server may continue to process the form. Otherwise, the server should immediately stop processing the form and respond with an error.

For More detailed Info: https://cloudunder.io/blog/csrf-token

Comment: This explains how to avoid CSRF attack, but not on my doubt!